# recursive menuItems not render properly

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Need help to fix the recursive dropdown menu.

please visit
http://plnkr.co/edit/1mKljtoS9R0gAdACLxu7?p=preview

this app is not for desktop only. open preview in separate window, or you will not see the menus.

the menus do not drop down as they suppose to. so please help

```
        //index.html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html ng-app="app">

            <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
            <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js"></script>

            <script src="script.js"></script>
            </head>

            <body ng-controller="menuCtrl">

            <script type="text/ng-template" id="tree-renderer.html">
             <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#{{menuItem.title}}">{{menuItem.title}}
                <b ng-if="menuItem.children.length > 0" class="caret"></b></a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-submenu" ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItem.children" ng-include="'tree-renderer.html'"></li>
             </ul>
            </script>

            <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">VARCITI</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems" ng-include="'tree-renderer.html'"></li>
                          </ul>
                          </div>
                    </div>
            </div>

                    <div id="main" class="container main">
                        <div ng-view></div>
                    </div>
            </body>
            </html>


    // script.js
        var app = angular.module('app', []);

        app.controller('menuCtrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.menuItems = [{"id":3,"title":"Breaks","children":[{"id":32,"title":"Recon","children":[{"id":322,"title":"Transactions","children":[]},{"id":321,"title":"Matching","children":[]}]},{"id":31,"title":"Exception","children":[]}]},{"id":4,"title":"Reference","children":[{"id":46,"title":"User Setup","children":[{"id":463,"title":"User Role","children":[]},{"id":462,"title":"User Group","children":[]},{"id":461,"title":"User","children":[]}]},{"id":44,"title":"Currency","children":[{"id":443,"title":"FX Rates","children":[]},{"id":441,"title":"Currency","children":[]},{"id":442,"title":"Currency Group","children":[]}]},{"id":45,"title":"Product Code","children":[]},{"id":41,"title":"Instrument","children":[]},{"id":43,"title":"Party","children":[{"id":435,"title":"Legal Entity","children":[]},{"id":431,"title":"Broker","children":[]},{"id":434,"title":"Client","children":[]},{"id":433,"title":"Exchange","children":[]},{"id":432,"title":"Trader","children":[]}]},{"id":42,"title":"Trading Account","children":[]}]},{"id":2,"title":"Rules","children":[{"id":21,"title":"Rate Matrix","children":[{"id":211,"title":"Rates","children":[]},{"id":212,"title":"Charges","children":[]}]},{"id":22,"title":"Matching","children":[]},{"id":23,"title":"Transformation","children":[]}]},{"id":1,"title":"Analytics","children":[{"id":12,"title":"Transactions","children":[]},{"id":13,"title":"Reports","children":[]},{"id":11,"title":"Dashboard","children":[]}]},{"id":5,"title":"Review","children":[{"id":56,"title":"Invoice","children":[{"id":562,"title":"Receipt","children":[]},{"id":561,"title":"Generation","children":[]}]},{"id":54,"title":"Matching","children":[{"id":543,"title":"GU2 Recon","children":[]},{"id":542,"title":"Monthly","children":[]},{"id":541,"title":"Daily","children":[{"id":5412,"title":"Monthly","children":[]},{"id":5411,"title":"Daily","children":[]}]}]},{"id":53,"title":"Invoice","children":[{"id":532,"title":"Capture","children":[]},{"id":531,"title":"Recon","children":[]}]},{"id":51,"title":"Cost Center","children":[]},{"id":52,"title":"Manual Accruals","children":[{"id":521,"title":"View/Create","children":[]},{"id":523,"title":"Review","children":[]},{"id":522,"title":"Bulk Upload","children":[]}]},{"id":55,"title":"Exception","children":[]}]}];
        });

    //styles.css

    .dropdown-submenu {
        position: relative;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        margin-top: -6px;
        margin-left: -1px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
        border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu>a:after {
        display: block;
        content: " ";
        float: right;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-color: transparent;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
        border-left-color: #ccc;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-right: -10px;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
        border-left-color: #fff;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
        float: none;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
        left: -100%;
        margin-left: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
        border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    }
```

Comment: At least in the Plunker:  **Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery**

Comment: accidently remove jquery while trim down the code. added back, thanks

Answer (score 0):

problem found, somehow # in the href `href="#{{menuItem.title}}"` causes exception. it works after removing #. Can someone explain the reason ?

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #View/Create jquery-2.1.1.js:1437
Sizzle.error jquery-2.1.1.js:1437
Sizzle.tokenize jquery-2.1.1.js:2051
Sizzle.select jquery-2.1.1.js:2452
Sizzle jquery-2.1.1.js:843
jQuery.fn.extend.find jquery-2.1.1.js:2668
jQuery.fn.init jquery-2.1.1.js:2776
jQuery jquery-2.1.1.js:76
getParent bootstrap.js:775
(anonymous function) bootstrap.js:758
jQuery.extend.each jquery-2.1.1.js:375
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery-2.1.1.js:139
clearMenus bootstrap.js:757
Dropdown.toggle bootstrap.js:699
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-2.1.1.js:4409
elemData.handle jquery-2.1.1.js:4095
```